# VueJs how to get data from Vue.component

Tags: vuejs2

I want to know how to get data from Vue.component and send to 
this >>var app = new Vue({ })<<
this is my code

```
Vue.component('my-form', {
template: '#my-form',
props:['ddTechtemp'],
     data: function () {
     return {
        isCores: app.testCorres,
        activeClass: 'isCorrespon',
        errorClass: 'isTech',
        tempData : {cell1 : "",
                    cell2 : "",
                    cell3 : "",
                    cell4 : "",
                    cell5 : "",
                    cell6 : ""
        },
    }
},
watch:{
    tempData:{
        handler:function(newVal,oldVal){

            app.ddTechtemp = newVal;

        },
        deep:true,
    }

},
methods:{

}});
```

I want to get data from above code and send to this code `var app = new Vue({ data: Vue.component.data})`

Anyone understand me please help.Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing data to components in vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34534151/passing-data-to-components-in-vue-js)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In Vue.js parent-child relationship is run by

1) passing props from parent to child

2) emitting custom events from child to parent

So, if you need to pass some data from child to parent - use `this.$emit` to emit a custom event with your data, and listen for this event in parent component with `v-on:myevent` or `@myevent` shorthand. The data you pass with event is found in `$event` variable.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/wostex/63t082p2/51/

```
<div id="app">
  <myform @newdata="handleData($event)"></myform>
  <p>name: {{ user.name }}</p>
  <p>age: {{ user.age }}</p>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    user: { name: '', age: 0 }
  },
  methods: {
    handleData: function(e) {
      [this.user.name, this.user.age] = e;
    }
  },
  components: {
    'myform': {
      template: `
      <div>
      <input type="text" v-model="formData.name" placeholder="Your name">
      <input type="number" v-model.number="formData.age">
      </div>`,
      data: function() {
        return { formData: { name: '', age: 0 } }
      },
      watch: {
        formData: {
            handler: function() {
              this.$emit('newdata', [this.formData.name, this.formData.age]);
          },
            deep: true
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: perfect. Thank Wostex

Comment: wostex I have a few question. how  to push every data of component to some array now when I click button and console.log data it show the last component but in watch it show unique when I edit it

Comment: @KemBardly I don't understand your question. Can you make a workable fiddle?

Comment: thanks a lot. what if I have multi components, is there any interference happened between other data that I want to take from another components? thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to work with advanced things like a Vuex store for ''state management'' but for simple implementations one additional reactive component would work as well.
in `src/store/index.js`

```
import { reactive } from 'vue';

export const store = reactive({
  some_id : 0,
});
```

And in a component `src/component/SelectComponent.vue`

```
<script setup>
import { store } from "@/store";
</script>

<script>
export default {
  name: "SelectComponent",
  // rest of the component source here
}
</script>

<template>
  <select v-model="store.some_id">
    <option v-for="itm in list" :key=itm.id" :value="itm.id">{{ itm.text }}</option>
  </select>
</template>
```

Using the component in `src/views/SomeView.vue`

```
<script setup>
import { store } from "@/store";
import SelectComponent from "@/components/SelectComponent"
</script>

<script>
//... use store.some_id in some method
</script>
```

You can store all your global variables in the store/index.js file and keep reactive. You might want to add `watch`ers to observe the store variable(s).

WARNING: this is discouraged for large, complex Vue applications
NOTE: this is an easy approach for simple state management not requrring Vuex with all the `actions` and `mutations`, `state`s and `context`s - plumbing.