# How to load data in Vue.js app

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I used the vue cli webpack to generate an app. Now I'm trying to load some data into a view without success. Here is code in current state:

main.js

```js
// The Vue build version to load with the `import` command
// (runtime-only or standalone) has been set in webpack.base.conf with an alias.
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'

import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.use(BootstrapVue)

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  components: { App },
  template: '<App/>',
  data: {
    exchanges: [
      {name: 'gdax', price: 1450},
      {name: 'bitfinex', price: 1525}
    ]
  }
})
```

App.vue

```html
<template>

  <div id="app" class="container">
    <h1>Arb Bot</h1>
    <router-view/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'App'
  }
</script>

<style>
  #app {
    font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    color: #2c3e50;
    margin-top: 60px;
  }
</style>
```

routes/index.js

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import HelloWorld from '@/components/HelloWorld'
import Opportunities from '@/components/Opportunities'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'HelloWorld',
      component: HelloWorld
    },
    {
      path: '/opportunities',
      name: 'Opportunities',
      component: Opportunities
    }
  ]
})
```

Opportunities.vue

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <h2>Bitcoin prices</h2>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Exchange</td><td>Price</td>
      </tr>
      <tr v-for="exchange in exchanges" :key="exchange.name">
        <td>{{ exchange.name }}</td><td>{{ exchange.price }}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>
```

The view is rendering fine except the `data` isn't loading so the table rows with the exchange names aren't showing up in the browser.

How can I properly load the data into the view and print the table?

Thanks

Comment: `exchanges` is a root level data property. You will have to pass it as a property to the `Opportunities.vue` component.

Comment: Like so: https://codesandbox.io/s/jjrw9rjy93. Alternatively, use a state management system like Vuex.

Comment: Vuex version for fun https://codesandbox.io/s/oqvmp4rmz6

Comment: Here is an answer that explains the passing arguments to the component
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34541828/6805529

Answer (score -2):

```
el: '#app',
```

refers to the element with ID=app, which in your case is missing.

You can fix it by giving the table the id=app

```
<table id="app">
```

Comment: I added the code from App.vue above. `id="app"` is included there