# Laravel 6 How to pass parameter to Vue Js @click method

Tags: laravel, vue.js, onclick, laravel-6

I want to pass a parameter to Vue component. please help

**Blade**

```
@extends("./layouts.app")
@section("title")
 {{$shop->shop_name}}
@endsection


@section("content")
 <addToCart></addToCart>
@endsection
```

**Vue Js**

```
<template>
  <div class="button-container">
   <button @click="addToCart(product_id)">Add To Cart</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Does the `addToCart` component have any properties?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing data to components in vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34534151/passing-data-to-components-in-vue-js)

Comment: @Jerodev no addToCart component doest have any properties

Comment: @Francois_Borgies NO I want to pass a parameter to addToCart method from the blade...  addToCart("parameter")

Comment: @Anas do you have the product_id in laravel side.

Comment: @Dawlatzai_Ghousi  yes I am fetching it from the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your **Vue Js** 
add new prop array

```
<template>
      <div class="button-container">
       <button @click="addToCart(product_id)">Add To Cart</button>
      </div>
    </template>
    <script>
    export default {
      props: ["product_id"],
      methods: {
       addToCart(product_id) 
       {
        //code
       }
    }
    </script>
```

in your **Blade** add :product_id ="product id", in addToCart component.

```
@extends("./layouts.app")
@section("title")
 {{$shop->shop_name}}
@endsection


@section("content")
 <addToCart :product_id="***product id goes here***"></addToCart>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

You should follow these steps to access `product_id`

1. inside your addToCart component add product_id like this:

   `@section("content")
    <addToCart :product_id="$product_id"></addToCart>
   @endsection`
2. in your component you should get the `:product_id` with `props array` like below :

   `<template>
     <div class="button-container">
      <button @click="addToCart(product_id)">Add To Cart</button>
     </div>
   </template> 
   <script>
   export default {
     props: ["product_id"],
     methods: {
       addToCart(product_id) {
       //code
      }
   }
   </script>`

***Note***: I suppose that you have the `product_id` and you do the other part of component correct.