# Get to display the right product info using json file and Due js

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vuejs2

The idea would be selecting a product by clicking on view Details button from PortfolioV3.vue  and take you to ProductDetail.vue according to the product selected but I can't seem to find a way to make this link. What would be the most efficient way to configure this value passing information taken from json file from one PortfolioV3.vue to ProductDetail.vue?

portfolio-v3.json

```
    {
  "data":[
   {
     "image_path":"static/products/DELUXE-BATHROBE.jpg",
      "title":"Productivity Tools",
      "title_color":"bg-info",
      "heading":"Deluxe Bathrobe",
      "read_more_url":"javascript:void(0);",
      "content": "bathrobe posuere proin blandit accumsan senectus netus nullam curae, ornare laoreet adipiscing luctus mauris adipiscing pretium eget fermentum, tristique lobortis est ut metus lobortis tortor."
   },
   {
     "image_path":"static/products/HERRINGBONE-THERMAL-BLANKET.jpg",
      "title":"Productivity Tools",
      "title_color":"badge-warning",
      "heading":"Herringbone Thermal Blanket",
      "read_more_url":"javascript:void(0);",
      "content": "blanket posuere proin blandit accumsan senectus netus nullam curae, ornare laoreet adipiscing luctus mauris adipiscing pretium eget fermentum, tristique lobortis est ut metus lobortis tortor."
   },
   {
     "image_path":"static/products/MADISON-SPREAD-BLANKETS.jpg",
      "title":"Productivity Tools",
      "title_color":"bg-yellow",
      "heading":"Madison Spread Blankets",
      "read_more_url":"javascript:void(0);",
      "content": "blanket posuere proin blandit accumsan senectus netus nullam curae, ornare laoreet adipiscing luctus mauris adipiscing pretium eget fermentum, tristique lobortis est ut metus lobortis tortor."
   }
  ]
}
```

PortfolioV3.vue

```
<template>
   <div>
      <PageTitle
         headerTitle="Our Latest Work"
         headerSubTitle="We build something great in the world."
      >
      </PageTitle>
      <div class="portfolio-wrapper section-gap port-3">
         <div class="container">
            <div class="blog-alternate" v-for="(portfolio,index) of portfoliov3.data" :key="index">
               <div class="row align-items-center">
                  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                     <div class="overlay-wrap">
                        <img :src="portfolio.image_path" width="500" height="500" class="img-fluid border-rad w-100" alt="gallery images" />
                        <a :href="portfolio.image_path" data-fancybox="images" class="card-img-overlay primary-tp-layer pos-center text-center">
                           <span class="center-holder">
                              <a class="ih-fade-down square-40 rounded-circle bg-white shadow-md">
                                 <i class="fa fa-plus align-middle"></i>
                              </a>
                           </span>
                        </a>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                     <div class="portfolio-content">
                        <h5 :class="portfolio.title_color" class="badge p-2 mb-3 btn-pill"> {{portfolio.title}} </h5>
                        <h3 class="mb-3"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="text-dark">{{portfolio.heading}}</a></h3>
                        <p class="mb-4">{{portfolio.content}}</p>
                        <a :href="portfolio.read_more_url" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-chk-dark"> READ MORE </a>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</template>
<script>
   import portfoliov3 from 'Components/data/portfolio-v3.json'
   export default {
      data(){
         return{
            portfoliov3
         }
      }
   }
</script>
```

ProductDetail.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="product-wrapper section-gap pb-0">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row mb-4">
          <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6">
            <div class="mb-4">
              <div class="feature-box-thumb">
                <img src="static/img/2.jpg" class="img-fluid card-shadow" alt="product image" />
              </div>
              <!-- feature box thumb closed -->
            </div>
            <div class>
              <ul class="list-unstyled p-gallary-thumb list-p-detail row">
                <li class="col-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 mb-4">
                  <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                    <img src="static/img/2.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="product image" />
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li class="col-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 mb-4">
                  <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                    <img src="static/img/2.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="product image" />
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li class="col-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 mb-4">
                  <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                    <img src="static/img/2.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="product image" />
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li class="col-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 mb-4">
                  <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                    <img src="static/img/2.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="product image" />
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 product-detail-content mb-4">
            <div class="mb-3">
              <h2 class="text-capitalize mb-3">Fleece Jacket</h2>
              <!--<h4 class="font-26 text-primary">
                <del class="text-muted mr-2">$187</del> $125.00
              </h4>-->
            </div>
            <div class="mb-4">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque quis eros lobortis, vestibulum turpis ac, pulvinar odio. Praesent vulputate a elit ac mollis. In sit amet ipsum turpis.</p>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque quis eros lobortis, vestibulum turpis ac, pulvinar odio. Praesent vulputate a elit ac mollis. In sit amet ipsum turpis. Pellentesque venenatis, libero vel euismod lobortis, mi metus luctus augue, eget dapibus elit nisi eu massa. Phasellus sollicitudin nisl posuere nibh ultricies.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-4">
              <p class="mb-0">
                <span class="font-weight-bold">Category :</span>
                <a href="#">Electronics</a>,
                <a href="#">Lights</a>,
                <a href="#">Solar</a>
              </p>
            </div>
            <div></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      <!-- container closed -->
    </div>
    <!-- product wrapper closed -->
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import RelatedProducts from "Components/Sections/RelatedProducts.vue";
import portfoliov2 from "Components/data/portfolio-v2.json";

export default {
  components: {
    RelatedProducts
  },
  data() {
    return {
      portfoliov2
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing data to components in vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34534151/passing-data-to-components-in-vue-js)

Comment: This example only shows using data passed on html url. In my case, all the content is obtained from json file. The list is populated using v-for. When click on button, I need to pass the product selected to the Product details page so it displays the correct information for the product selected.